# Clarification to Solution from *Spivak's Calculus* - Ch. 14, Q. 15c

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, proof-explanation

The following is a question from *Spivak's Calculus*, Ch.14 - 15c.

[image]

My question pertains to showing the "if and only if" part is true, i.e establishing that $f(a) = f(0)$. I worked on it for a bit, thinking of how to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to the question since that is the main topic of Ch.14, but I was not able to accomplish anything. Then I looked at the solution and I'm very perplexed by what the steps are. Here is the solution:

[image]

The objective is to show $f(a) = f(0)$. I can understand defining a new function $g(x) = f(x + a) - f(x)$, the reason behind it not so much. It appears to me from such a definition that if we could somehow show $f(x + a) = f(x)$ then we would establish the periodicity.

So we take the derivative of $g(x)$, this shows $g(x)$ is actually a constant. In particular we can then take $g(0)$ to get constant value $g(0) = f(a) - f(0)$. This somehow implies

$$f(x + a) = f(x) + f(a) - f(0)$$

I'm not sure exactly how this comes about. I could vaguely see a rearranging of $g(x) + f(x) = f(x + a)$, and I suppose since $g(x)$ is a constant, were we to take the derivative of both sides nothing would be affected. But I'm still not completely clear o the reasoning.

The steps involving $f(na) = nf(a) - (n-1)f(0)$ have me completely befuddled to the point I can't even attempt to explain my way through it.

Some clarification on what is being attempted would be appreciated.

Comment: $f$ might not have period $a$ but we know that $f'$ does. So we don't know that $f(x+a)= f(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x) := f(x+a)-f(x)$. Then, since $f'$ is $a$-periodic, $g'(x) = 0$, which means $g$ is constant. In particular, $g(x) = g(0)$ for all $x$, that is,
$$f(x+a)-f(x) = f(a)-f(0) \quad \textrm{for all $x$,}$$
or, equivalently,
$$f(x+a) = f(x) + f(a)-f(0) \quad \textrm{for all $x$.} \tag{$*$}$$
Now observe that if we put $x=a$ in $(*)$ we obtain
$$f(2a) = 2f(a)-f(0),$$
and then putting $x=2a$ in $(*)$, and using the latter equation, we obtain
\begin{align}
f(3a) &= f(2a)+f(a)-f(0) \\
&= [2f(a)-f(0)] +f(a)-f(0)
= 3f(a)-2f(0).
\end{align}
Then, continuing with this pattern (prove this by induction) it follows that
$$f(an) = nf(a)-(n-1)f(a)$$
for every positive integer $n$.